Ant Design - How to display "Segmented" vertically?
I've encountered a problem: I need to somehow display the "Segmented" component vertically, instead of the default horizontally.
Tried overriding the parent's style to make it flex-direction: column. Yes, it becomes vertical, but there are problems with hover/active animation when switching.
import React from 'react';
import { UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Avatar, Flex, Segmented } from 'antd';
const App = () => (
  <Flex gap="small" align="flex-start" vertical>
    <Segmented
      options={[
        {
          label: (
            <div
              style={{
                padding: 4,
              }}
            >
              <Avatar src="https://api.dicebear.com/7.x/miniavs/svg?seed=8" />
              <div>User 1</div>
            </div>
          ),
          value: 'user1',
        },
        {
          label: (
            <div
              style={{
                padding: 4,
              }}
            >
              <Avatar
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#f56a00',
                }}
              >
                K
              </Avatar>
              <div>User 2</div>
            </div>
          ),
          value: 'user2',
        },
        {
          label: (
            <div
              style={{
                padding: 4,
              }}
            >
              <Avatar
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '#87d068',
                }}
                icon={<UserOutlined />}
              />
              <div>User 3</div>
            </div>
          ),
          value: 'user3',
        },
      ]}
    />
  </Flex>
);
export default App;


Antd segment is not designed for vertical direction. You can create a feature request in antd repo

There is no options for vertical display to this component.If modifying with CSS have some problems you can create an issue on Antd repo. Here the issue create link:
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/new/choose
